# visual studio 2008 collapse html in IDE like regions

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there anyway to collapse html in the IDE? For example if I have a table, I would like to collapse the table and anything inside of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a baked in feature of Visual Studio.  In the source view of an HTML page (.html, .master, .aspx, .ascx, etc.), there should be small plus signs next to collapsible elements.  Click that to collapse that element (and anything inside it).  Likewise, click the minus signs to expand them again.

Comment: for some reason it wasn't showing up.  i restarted VS and then it worked.